# How to add gradient to header ExpansionTile in Flutter

Tags: flutter, header, gradient, expand

Im trying to achieve certain look in my ExpansionTile, 
1. When collapsed solid header color
2. When expanded gradient in header only not in the body with elements.

This is what im trying to achieve:
[image]

Im trying with this code:

```
            Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                //brightness: Brightness.dark,
                primaryColor: Colors.black87,
                accentColor: Colors.black87,
                dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1, color: Color.fromRGBO(121, 85, 72, 1)),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                        end: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                       // stops: [0.1, 1.0],
                       // tileMode: TileMode.clamp,


                        colors: [
                          isExpanded
                              ? Color.fromRGBO(255,255,255,100)
                              : Color.fromRGBO(197, 181, 176, 1),
                          Color.fromRGBO(197, 181, 176, 1)//closed solid
                        ])),
                // color: Colors.brown,
                child: ExpansionTile(
              //backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                  trailing: isExpanded //assets/collapse_arrow.png
                      ? Image.asset('assets/collapse_arrow.png')
                      : Image.asset('assets/expand_arrow.png'),
                  onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) =>
                      setState(() => isExpanded = expanding),
                  title: Text(
                    'Header',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[

                    _dropDownItem('Rank', _selectRankFamily2,
                        _rankFamily2, 'Select Rank'),
                    _dropDownItem('Rank', _selectRankFamily2,
                        _rankFamily2, 'Select Rank'),
                    _dropDownItem('Rank', _selectRankFamily2,
                        _rankFamily2, 'Select Rank')
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

but i get this result:
[image]

So gradient is all the way not just header, is there a way to make gradient or solid color for header part only and only when expanded?
Thank you/

*Edit
If I use sugested answere to wrap only TITLE i got this result:

[image]

So i need to wrap trailing icon too somehow or what? Or maybe to make "fake" expandable box on top..

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the whole expansion tile with container, instead you should wrap only the title widget, this might be what you are looking for

```
Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        //brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.black87,
        accentColor: Colors.black87,
        dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        trailing: isExpanded //assets/collapse_arrow.png
            ? Image.asset('assets/collapse_arrow.png')
            : Image.asset('assets/expand_arrow.png'),
        onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) =>
            setState(() => isExpanded = expanding),
        title: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border:
                  Border.all(width: 1, color: Color.fromRGBO(121, 85, 72, 1)),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  end: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                  // stops: [0.1, 1.0],
                  // tileMode: TileMode.clamp,

                  colors: [
                    isExpanded
                        ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 100)
                        : Color.fromRGBO(197, 181, 176, 1),
                    Color.fromRGBO(197, 181, 176, 1) //closed solid
                  ])),
          child: Text(
            'Header',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        children: <Widget>[
          _dropDownItem(
              'Rank', _selectRankFamily2, _rankFamily2, 'Select Rank'),
          _dropDownItem(
              'Rank', _selectRankFamily2, _rankFamily2, 'Select Rank'),
          _dropDownItem('Rank', _selectRankFamily2, _rankFamily2, 'Select Rank')
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this,

> If you check the source code of the ExpansionTitle , you will notice that the header item is a ListTile , so you can't change the background because it hasn't a parent with a color property.
>   I modified a little the class to support what you need.

Add this file to your project: https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/02424eebd4d6e06ae649b31e4ebcf53c<

Now is there a simular way to overdrive Gradient property instad of solid color?